# Отсортировать многомерный массив по значению на php

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Есть многомерный массив, нужно отсортировать по 2 значениям. Пока реализовал только по 1, как можно дополнить:

```
$results = array(
    array(1,98,1),
    array(2,75,2),
    array(3,20,3),
    array(4,17,2),
    array(5,56,3),
    array(2,77,1),
    array(6,23,1),
    array(3,77,1),
    array(7,100,2),
    array(1,50,2)
);
uasort($results, function($a,$b) {
    return ($a[2]-$b[2]);
});
```

Мне нужно чтобы была также сортировка по `$a[1]` по убыванию с сохранением ключей. Для наглядности прикрепляю скин правильного порядка для первых 4 элементов массива[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не бывает сортировки по 2 критериям. Соберите из двух один составной - и всё станет элементарно. Ну типа (без оглядки на синтаксис) `return ($a[2]-$b[2]=0 ? $a[1]-$b[1] : $a[2]-$b[2])`

Comment: *Мне нужно чтобы была также сортировка по $a[1] по убыванию с сохранением ключей. Для наглядности прикрепляю скин правильного порядка для первых 4 элементов массива* А как по мне, так во 2-3 элементах при равном $a[2] сортировка по $a[1] показана по возрастанию... или у нас что-то в законодательстве поменялось?

Comment: Да, действительно, извините, поправлю чтобы не было путаницы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто расширяете проверку таким образом:

```
uasort($results, function($a,$b) {
    if (($a[2]==$b[2])){
        return ($b[1]-$a[1]); 
    }else{
        return ($a[2]-$b[2]);
    } 
});
```

Чтобы изменить направление достаточно `$a` и `$b` местами поменять

Comment: Спасибо вам, самый простой вариант и наиболее рациональный

Comment: То же, что предложил я, один в один, только не тернарным оператором, а `IF()`. Ну может так и вправду кому-то понятнее...

Comment: @Akina, не совсем, добавлено так-же указание по сортировке

Comment: Не, это не в порядке каких-то там претензий. Просто есть ли смысл в таком простом случае пользовать IF? А насчёт порядка - так у тебя по вторичному признаку как раз по возрастанию получается, а не как в вопросе. Впрочем, это мелочь, недостойная внимания.

Comment: @Akina, зачем тернарный оператор, когда можно `$a[2]-$b[2] ?: $a[1]-$b[1]` ;-)

Comment: Code golf устроили тут)